# gnuplot date with dashes then time

Tags: time, format, gnuplot

I am still struggling.  It just seems either create nothing or
a plot with everything jammed into a single period.
The line data is supposed to be
YYYY-MM-DD,HH:MM,HH:MM,n.nn,kwh.
where the hours and  minutes are start and end times.
I just want the start  ( or end ) time, not the interval.
And to plot the date time and usage in kwh ( the n.nn) value
My sample plot script is.

```
#Sat Oct  1 03:28:14 PM EDT 2022
# plot usage 15 minute intervals
# first line ( without the # 
#2021-09-08,00:00,00:14,0.69,kWh,
# last line
#2021-10-06,23:45,23:59,0.21,kWh,
set terminal png size 1920,1280

#set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y"
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M"
#set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"

set xlabel "Date"
set xrange ["2021-09-08,00:00":"2021-10-06,23:45"]
#set xrange ["10/07/2019,00:00":"09/07/2022,23:59"]  # no errors and no data x range is  10:9

set ylabel "Interval usage KWH"
set datafile separator ","
set title "AEP Interval"
set output "Interval.png"
plot "aepo_electric_interval_data_Service_1_2021-09-08_to_2021-10-06.csv" using 1:4
```

This generates
$ ./intervalPlot
"./intervalPlot" line 24: Can't plot with an empty x range!

I tried using 1:3 and using 1:2... no joy

Answer (score 0):

You were close. I see two minor problems:

1. You need to tell gnuplot what to do with the time format. In this case you want to use it for the x-axis coordinate, so the command is `set xdata time`.
2. There is a missing keyword `using`.

```
    set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
    set xdata time
    plot "interval.csv" using 1:4 with linespoints
```

[image]

Also, if that really is a csv file, you may also need to give the field separator character (tab, I suppose?).

```
set datafile separator tab
```